# Trouble with imp.load_source: 'module' has no attribute 'foo'

Tags: python, import, module, imp, python-importlib

I have a directory filled with an arbitrary number of modules, each of which contains only a function `do_stuff`. For example:

```
foos/
    __init__.py
    foo_1.py
    foo_2.py
    ...
    foo_n.py
```

foo_1.py, for example, could just be:

```
def do_stuff(bar):
    if bar.blah:
        return True
    return False
```

From elsewhere in the code, I want to collect and run all the `do_stuff` functions. I though this would be easy with the `imp` module:

```
import imp
...
...

FOOS_DIR = os.path.join(MY_HOME, 'foos/') 
MOD_REGEX = r'^(?!__).*\.py$'                                            

foos = [imp.load_source(fname.split('.py')[0], FOOS_DIR)              
            for fname in os.listdir(FOOS_DIR)                         
               if re.match(MOD_REGEX, fname)]                          

results = [foo.do_stuff('argument!') for foo in foos]
```

However, this leads to:

```
AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'do_stuff'"
```

From the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path), I thought this was the way to go. If it is, maybe my syntax is off? After all, `load_source` is really forgiving:

```
(pdb) imp.load_source('not_there', FOOS_DIR)
<module 'not_there' from '/home/blah/blah/foos'>
```

Otherwise, what could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a syntax issue! I need the full path *to the module file*, not just its directory, as the second argument to `load_source`:

Thus,

```
foos = [imp.load_source(fname.split('.py')[0], FOOS_DIR)              
            for fname in os.listdir(FOOS_DIR)                         
               if re.match(MOD_REGEX, fname)]
```

Becomes

```
foos = [imp.load_source(fname.split('.py')[0], '%s%s' % (FOOS_DIR, fname))              
            for fname in os.listdir(FOOS_DIR)                         
               if re.match(MOD_REGEX, fname)]
```

And it works just fine!